# Raster Extrapolation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

Does QGIS (or different software) have a method to extrapolate raster values to larger area (outer boundary)?

I have a boundary(.shp), which is 40 m far from the edge of raster. I want to fill the space between raster edge and polygon boundary with values extrapolated from edges of raster. Some cubic spline method would be ideal.

[image]

Comment: Normally, cubic splines are about as bad as it gets: where there are regions of rapid change near the boundary, as there are here, the spline will rapidly extrapolate to hugely unrealistic values. The best advice for extrapolation will depend on why you want to do this extrapolation, so I hope you will be able to edit your post to provide that context. If you can find some way to avoid extrapolation altogether, that would be the best option. For instance, often such boundary problems result from a series of raster operations that trim edges; if so, start over with a slightly larger extent.